# odd and even numbers in c# with ternary

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

i need to use ternary if operator which you enter a number to textbox and it gives you that the number is odd or even number in checkboxes

```
int sayi1 = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);

if  (sayi1 % 2 == 0)? tek.Checked = true : cift.Checked = false;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What language are you using? You have shown what you have tried. How did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you need this:

```
int sayi1 = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
bool isEven = sayi1 % 2 == 0
tek.Checked = isEven
cift.Checked = !isEven;
```

I feel that the ternary operator is not a good fit for what you need because you are trying to set two different check boxes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer